# chrome opening form submit in new tab no data

Tags: forms, google-chrome, tabs, submit

I just noticed some strange behavior of Chrome. On my site there is a page that has a form which does a POST to a secure part of the site. However if I submit the form in Chrome using ctrl+left click (on the submit button) it opens a new window (as expected) but the request is a GET request rather than a GET request, and no form data is send. I tried to rule out all other things by making a test page with just a simple form:

```
<form method="post" action='https://secure.mysite.com/formtest2.php' target='_top'>
  <input type='text' name='element' value='blabla' />
  <input type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

and a receiving page:

```
<?php
 print "POST:";
 print_r($_POST);
 print "<br/>GET:";
 print_r($_GET);
?>
```

When I click the submit button (in Chrome) everything works as expected and I get:

POST:Array ( [my-element] => blabla )

GET:Array ( )

However when I use ctrl+click I see this in a new tab:

POST:Array ( )

GET:Array ( )

So my question is, is this normal behavior or a bug in Chrome (my version is 21.0.1180.83 m)? And is there anyway to prevent this from happening so I do not have to show the user some sort of error page redirecting him back and asking not to open the submit of the form in a new tab (UGLY!)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like sort of a bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=77565